# Java unexpected infinite loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop

My problems is that I have a method that enters into an unexpected infinite loop and I can't identify why. The method is supposed to take input from the user and assign it to three different objects. However, after the loop has run twice and has asked the user to input the name for the third object, the program loops infinitely. I should point out that I am still relatively new to java and learning to program in general.

Here is the code(I have started comments with !!!! that I believe are related to the problem):

```
private void readInput()    
//This method accepts input from the user about product data and sets the values of 
//product1, product2 and product3
//Also validates all input so as not to crash the program if the user enters incorrect data
{       
    String name;        
    int demandRate, productChoice=1; 
    final int MAXPRODUCTS=3;
    double setupCost, unitCost, inventoryCost, sellingPrice;

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (productChoice <= MAXPRODUCTS)    
    //A loop that makes the user enter data for all three products and then stops after the third entry
    {                                      
        System.out.println("Please enter the product's name: ");
        name = console.next();       
        matesStore.isAProduct(name);     // checks whether the product name the user has entered is unique.
        while (matesStore.isAProduct(name))  
        //If a name that has already been entered is found, the user will be asked to reenter the name
        {
            System.out.println("That name is already in use. Please choose another: "); 
            name = console.next();
        }
        while (!matesStore.isAProduct(name))
        //If a name has not been used, the name is added to the product
        {
            matesStore.addProduct(name); //!!!!I suspect the problem is this line.
        }            
        System.out.println("Please enter the product's demand rate: ");
        demandRate = console.nextInt();                         
        System.out.println("Please enter the product's setup cost: ");
        setupCost = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the product's unit cost: ");
        unitCost = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the product's inventory cost: ");
        inventoryCost = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the product's selling price: ");
        sellingPrice = console.nextDouble();
        matesStore.addData(productChoice, demandRate, setupCost, unitCost, inventoryCost, sellingPrice);    //Uses the method from the Store class to set the data values for the products.
        productChoice++;        
    }
    while (productChoice > MAXPRODUCTS)
    {
        System.out.println("The list is now full.");
        continueOption();
    }         
}//End of Method and Interface class
```

And this is the methods from the Store class:

```
public boolean isAProduct(String product)
//Returns true if a name has been found otherwise returns false
{
    boolean found = false;
    int counter = 0;

    while (!found && (counter < MAXNUMBEROFPRODUCTS))
    {
        if (product.equalsIgnoreCase(product1.getName()))
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else if (product.equalsIgnoreCase(product2.getName()))
        {
            found = true;                 
        }
        else 
        {
            counter++;
        }            
    }        

    return found;
}//End of method

public void addProduct(String product)
//If isAProduct() returns false then the product name 
//entered by the user is stored in product1, product2 and product3 respectively

//!!!!I think this is where the problem originates but can't figure out why
{   
    if (numberOfProducts == 0) 
    //!!!!numberOfProducts has been declared as private int numberOfProducts=0;
    //I tried declaring numberOfProducts as a variable within addProduct()
    //but that just set the value to 0 each time and so only the name for product1 was set
    {
        product1.setName(product);
        numberOfProducts++;
    }
    else if (numberOfProducts == 1)
    {
        product2.setName(product);
        numberOfProducts++;
    }
    else if (numberOfProducts == 2)
    {                
        product3.setName(product);
    }            
    else
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Cheers

Comment: The first loop condition is productChoice <= MAXPRODUCTS while the second is productChoice > MAXPRODUCTS. Is productChoice decreased in continueOption or is that a/the problem?

Comment: try inserting some debug statements, rather than trying to guess where it is looping.

Comment: what exactly is being printed, when your program enters to an infinite loop?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why productChoice would need to be decreased. It starts off at 1 and so is less than 3 and enters the loop and then at the end of the loop is increased by 1 so it becomes 2 and enters the loop again etc until the value gets to 4 in which case the loop ends and the user is notified that the list is full and then continueOption() takes the user back to the main interface. Should I be decreasing productChoice back to 0 after all that is done? Sorry, I'm just a little confused :)

Comment: @Zeeshan Nothing really, I enter the name for the third object and the program just stops accepting input. But it doesn't stop, I have to manually stop the program which is why I figured it was an infinite loop.

Comment: `and then continueOption() takes the user back to the main interface` - why have it in a `while` loop then?

Comment: You should use array for the products

Comment: When you step through your code in your debugger what do you see?  Is the `name` being added, or is it that it fails to find a match?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I could probably add it after the main while loop. However I don't believe that continueOption() is the problem since the program doesn't even get that far before entering the infinite loop.

Comment: Sky I haven't learnt to use arrays yet unfortunately :/

@PeterLawrey When I step through the debugger with a stop on matesStore.addProduct(name);, the name for both product1 and product 2 are being added with their all their details as well but then it asks for the name for product3 and after I enter it the program debugger won't let me continue but says that name for product3 is no longer the initial value but is the value I enter with the rest of the fields set at their initial value. This is when the program would normally just loop infinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (!matesStore.isAProduct(name))
        //If a name has not been used, the name is added to the product
        {
            matesStore.addProduct(name); //!!!!I suspect the problem is this line.
        }
```

The reason the 3rd product is infinite looping is because you should use If for this statement, while also work but you see there's an error is due to your method addProduct. If you change to If it won't be an infinite loop however your product 3 will be bugged.

```
public boolean isAProduct(String product)
//Returns true if a name has been found otherwise returns false
{
    boolean found = false;
    int counter = 0;

    while (!found && (counter < MAXNUMBEROFPRODUCTS))
    {
        if (product.equalsIgnoreCase(product1.getName()))
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else if (product.equalsIgnoreCase(product2.getName()))
        {
            found = true;                 
        }
        else 
        {
            counter++;
        }            
    }        

    return found;
}//End of method
```

Noticed that you don't check for product3, so it will always return false when searching for your 3rd product name.

!matesStore.isAProduct(name) = !false = true

Viola!! There you goes it's while(true), an infinite loop!

Fix by implementing the product3.getName() in your isAProduct() method.

Your code is messy, you should use array for the products and you can do a better search with an array.

```
public boolean isAProduct(String product)
//Returns true if a name has been found otherwise returns false
{
    boolean found = false;
    int counter = 0;

    while (!found && (counter < MAXNUMBEROFPRODUCTS))
    {
        if (product.equalsIgnoreCase(product1.getName()))
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else if (product.equalsIgnoreCase(product2.getName()))
        {
            found = true;                 
        }
        else if (product.equalsIgnoreCase(product3.getName()))
        {
            found = true;                 
        }
        else 
        {
            counter++;
        }            
    }        

    return found;
}//End of method
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to solve my problem with your advice :)
Also, this program is for a uni project that specifically requires us not to use arrays. We've only just started learning about them and our next assignment requires us to modify this program to use arrays haha

Comment: @user3610513 I see, no wonder you aren't using an array. An array would solve and making your codes more readable. And it's strange because I learnt arrays before learning methods. I thought it would be more important to learn about data types first before methods and classes. However reading your codes made me feeling more awake @ my workplace while I'm trying to debug your codes in my brain!

Comment: haha yeah that probably would make sense but it's up to the lecturer I guess. 
That's good though! I feel like I'm just being a pain asking such simple and probably blindingly obvious questions haha :)

Comment: @MrPigeon anyway i noted that you do not need the while loop for your `matesStore.addProduct(name);`

`while (!matesStore.isAProduct(name)){}` loop can be removed as previously you already verify that it should be correct before allowing the user to break out of the loop.

Comment: Yeah I've changed it now :)